# Errors validating salesrule programatically on 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3

After upgrading to Magento 2.3.2 (from 2.2.8) I am having a problem with a piece of custom code. I am running this as part of a block for displaying valid cart rules for a product.

```
public function getRules($product) {
    if (!$product) {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('product');
    }

    $_rules = $this->ruleFactory->create()->getCollection();

    foreach($_rules as $rule){
        $validate = $rule->getActions()->validate($product);
        if ($validate){
            // Do something
        }

    }

    // remaining omitted
}
```

The problematic part that I am running into is this line:

`$validate = $rule->getActions()->validate($product);`

It is throwing the following errors.

```
2019/07/25 12:22:26 [error] 5286#0: *7638021 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() on null in /site.com/dev/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Plugin/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php:59
Stack trace:
#0 /site.com/dev/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Plugin/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php(30): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product->getProductToValidate(Object(Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#1 /site.com/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Plugin\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product->beforeValidate(Object(Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#2 /site.com/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interc" while reading response header from upstream
```

My store only has simple products. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... apparently I needed the entire product model loaded.

Assuming `$this->product` is `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;`

`$item = $this->product->setProduct($product);`

`$validate = $rule->getActions()->validate($product);`

It now works

Comment: This help me. Thanks Adam!